# Hiding toolbar title only for one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

In my app I want to remove toolbar title for one fragment only. When I use the following code

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

it also removes title from all other fragments too. Is there any other way to remove title for only one fragment and keeping it in others. I also tried removing title attribute from navigation drawer implementation but then it starts showing app name in title. I don't want anything in this fragment . How this can be done?

Comment: In every fragment you need to maintain with that action bar, where to show and where to hide.

Comment: it is not happening. If I hide it once then it is not getting shown anywhere even if I made it visible in other fragments

Comment: Can't you just set text for that fragment to empty.

Comment: Are the fragments in a viewpager?

Comment: no they are with navigation drawer

Comment: @NigamPatro setting to empty worked. Thanks

Comment: that was the most obvious solution, I wanted to write that... cheers @NigamPatro